# Squashing tuples from (a,(b,c)) to (a,b,c) in fsharp

Tags: f#, tuples, inline, iterable-unpacking

Does it make sense to have such functions defined

```
let squash12 (e:('a*('b*'c)   )) = e |> (fun (a,(b,c)  ) -> (a,b,c  ))
let squash21 (e:(('a*'b)*'c   )) = e |> (fun ((a,b),c  ) -> (a,b,c  ))
let squash13 (e:('a*('b*'c*'d))) = e |> (fun (a,(b,c,d)) -> (a,b,c,d))

let seqsquash12 (sa:seq<'T>) = sa |> Seq.map squash12
let seqsquash21 (sa:seq<'T>) = sa |> Seq.map squash21
let seqsquash13 (sa:seq<'T>) = sa |> Seq.map squash13
```

I could not find another way to make my core code recursive (leading to nested tuples), yet expose simple function that maps to generalized n-dimensional coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have marked your functions as inline so that they could just be

```
let inline squash1 (a,(b,c)) = (a,b,c)
```

Also, you don't need the lambdas `(fun  ...)`

Comment: thks. I noticed type inference is slow (i use higher order stuff only for base functions), so I might as well specify the type  if it speeds it up.

Comment: @nicolas - really, I don't think type inferrence is slow + this version will be much faster at runtime (avoids a function call)

Comment: @nicolas: See my answer for a suggestion in generic cases.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it makes sense to do so. The suggestion is avoiding lambda to make these functions easier to read:

```
let squash12 (a, (b, c)) = a, b, c
```

If you encounter inner tuples with varied arity very often, converting them into lists is not a bad idea. For example, `e` becomes a tuple of two lists:

```
(a, (b, c)) ~> ([a], [b; c])
(a, b), c) ~> ([a; b], [c])
(a, (b, c, d)) ~> (a, [b; c; d])
```

And we only need one function for sequence:

```
let seqsquash sa = sa |> Seq.map (@)
```

The problem is you lose the control over size of input. Pattern matching on list could help:

```
let squash12 (xs, ys) = 
   match xs, ys with
   | [a], [b; c] -> xs, ys
   | _ -> failwith "Wrong input size"
```